# Fetching information from Youtube using JSON not working in FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, youtube-api

I am attempting to fetch data from Youtube via `JSON`. This code is running in Chrome well, but it is not working in Firefox. My code is as follows:

```
function test(url){

  var youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
  var video_id= youtube_id;
    $.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=json', function(data) {
    var title = data.entry.title.$t;
    var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
    var thumbnail = data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url; // URL of the image

   document.writeln(thumbnail);
   document.writeln(description);// Use these variables somewhere
});
}
```

Thanks in advance - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an error/stack trace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206648/how-to-get-video-image-url-in-youtube-using-json
This link will helpful for you

Comment: Manish My problem is already solved . this is really old post :) :).. BTW thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the datatype to the ajax request for it to work in firefox as well as chrome. Chrome automagically parses the JSON for your success callback, firefox does not.

so:

```
function test(url){

  var youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
  var video_id= youtube_id;
    $.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=json', function(data) {
    var title = data.entry.title.$t;
    var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
    var thumbnail = data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url; // URL of the image

   document.writeln(thumbnail);
   document.writeln(description);// Use these variables somewhere
}, "json");
}
```

works for me.

here is a jsfiddle that works in chrome and firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/8dyWr/1

and the get method signature:

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/