# how to get video image url in youtube using json

Tags: jquery, json, youtube

I am fetching youtube's single video data using json for that I am using following code

```
var video_id=KsnHky4wv5w;

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
            alert('getting jsomm');
            alert('title :'+data.data.title);
            alert(' \ndesc : '+ data.data.description);
            alert(' \n cat: '+ data.data.category);
            alert(' \ndura:'+data.data.duration);

        });
```

I am fetching title,description,category,duration properly,
but I am not able to fetch image url of video and its height and width.
How to find these.
JSON response of this video  id is [here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KsnHky4wv5w?v=2&alt=json)

Comment: Have you looked at the response in Firebug or similar? That will tell you what fields you have access to...

Comment: `console.log(data)` to see, what data you recieve. The image is inside `data.thumbnail` btw.

Comment: How have you tried to access these fields?

Comment: Yes I tried and got result. Thank you Tieson T. and @ArtyomNeustroev for teaching me how to get result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JSON response](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KsnHky4wv5w?v=2&alt=jsonc):

```
"thumbnail": {
   "sqDefault":"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/KsnHky4wv5w/default.jpg",
   "hqDefault":"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/KsnHky4wv5w/hqdefault.jpg"
}
```

Therefore

- *data.data.thumbnail.sqDefault*, for [standard quality](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/KsnHky4wv5w/default.jpg) or
- *data.data.thumbnail.hqDefault*, for [high quality](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/KsnHky4wv5w/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: how to get image size